# Programming advice on creating a class using class name

Tags: c#, createinstance

OK, I've searched and saw some questions on how to create a class using its name. My question is not quite the same, so I'm going to ask it anyway.

My application has 2 classes, say, "A" and "B". In another class, I need to use these two classes (the third class is called by an external service). The external service only passes me the names of the two "A" and "B" classes as string. In the third class, I know I can do something like:

```
case "A":
    create an instance of A
case "B":
    create an instance of B
```

but that seems weird. I'd like to do it dynamically so I was thinking of doing Activator.CreateInstance but not sure if it's good programming because it seems "CreateInstance" is used when you load an assembly remotely. In my case, everything is in one project.

Any advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` is both heavily used by the framework, and heavily optimized.  There is nothing wrong with its use.

Comment: The weird *case "A": create instance [...]* you mentioned is also known as the Factory Design Pattern (maybe not as well structured as it should be, but you can use `switch/case` for that). You can read about this pattern here: http://dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx and here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68670/The-Factory-Pattern

Comment: In addition to the links above, it's worth pointing out that you may want to look into an Inversion of Control framework like Spring.NET, Castle Windsor, or StructureMap if you are running into this pattern a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect case for using Factory Method pattern.

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If number of classes that you want to create by their name is limited (such as 2 different classes in your example), I would prefer the way with "switch"

```
public object ClassFactory(string ClassName)
{
    switch(ClassName)
    {
        case "A": return new A();
        case "B": return new B();
    }
}
```

because it is both faster and safer (if name of class comes from external service, imagine what would happen, if this service sends malicious class name).

Otherwise Activator.CreateInstance should not make any problem, but make sure, you thoroughly verify input.

Comment: I thought it would be faster too but not elegant. I'm still a junior programmer and trying to learn some experts' good skills. Thank you.